# .htaccess rule for redirecting everything to https:// that thing

Tags: .htaccess, https

What is the proper .htacess rule to redirect every request by a user to any page on my server to `https://that page`

For example, `mydomain.com` or `http://mydomain.com` would go to `https://mydomain.com`

Also, `mydomain.com/projects/1.html` would go to `https://my domain.com/projects/1.html`

No matter how deep the requests go, all requests from the browser go to be `https://that location.`

How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*) https://mydomain.tld$1
```

Ensure the vhosts are in different folders so it doesn't go recursive obviously.

Comment: What is the difference between this and the other answer? Do I have to use mod_ssl by using the SSLRequireSSL Directive?

Comment: All SSL directives only matter for the SSL site itself. What you're trying to achieve is just have a HTTP-host that redirects all calls to another vhost. The other answer is more generic and allows you to have the htaccess in the same vhost.

Comment: Ah, okay. What does `.tld$1` mean? And how can I ensure the vhosts are in different folders so it doesn't go recursively?

Comment: On most control panel based hosting servers they are, otherwise ensure the 80 and 443 listeners are in different DocumentRoots. Alternatively use the RewriteCond statement from the other answer to prevent recursion. The .tld$1 part is the replacing part of the regular expression that ensures the subpath remains the same after the redirect.

Comment: ah, I see. Thank you for the help. One last question. What do I replace mydomain with, the whole domain or just the part for the .com ? so is it `mydomain.tld$1` or `mydomain.com.tld$1` ?

Comment: TLD means 'top level domain', so for example .com or .net. So `mydomain.tld` was just a placeholder for `facebook.com` or whatever your domain is as a whole.

Comment: Ah, okay. so all that needs to go after the domain is `$1` ?

Comment: A `RewriteRule` matches on the URI, the part after the domain in a URL. So `(.*)` matches the entire URI, and then in the redirect you 'stick' it after the target domain to construct a new URL.

Comment: Okay, so the redirection to `https://that thing` works, but I get this error as seen in this screenshot: http://cl.ly/image/2h2x2t0K3X2I. What is wrong? How do I fix it?

Comment: That's an SSL configuration error, outside the scope of this question. Check your Apache error logs.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Apache, you need to use mod_ssl by using the SSLRequireSSL Directive.
then you need to use mod_rewrite for a redirection.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```